# Differentiate between the custom installed fonts and Office Application built-in(default) fonts in C# vsto

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am new in the .Net world. I am writing an Addin in C#(vsto) for Excel, where I want read out all the font styles available in the given Excel file.
I would like to know if the user has any fonts custom installed for the Office Application. The below piece of code helps retrieve all the installed font including both custom installed and default office fonts.

```
InstalledFontCollection installedFontCollection = new InstalledFontCollection();
FontFamily[] fontFamilies = installedFontCollection.Families;
```

Could you please let me know if there is anyway to programmatically distinguish between the default Office Application fonts and Custom installed?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of fonts available in Office applications by using the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub listFonts()
    Dim wd As Object, fontID As Variant

    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    For Each fontID In wd.FontNames
        Sheet1.cmbFonts.AddItem fontID
    Next
    wd.Quit
    Set wd = Nothing
End Sub
```

The [FontNames Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.fontnames?view=word-pia) represents a list of the names of all the available fonts. You cannot add names to or remove names from the list of available font names.

There is no other way to distinguish built-in or other fonts. I suppose Office applications always deal with installed fonts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However when I tried it in C# - Type ExcelType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application"); I couldnt find an object containing the list of all the default Office fonts. Could you please help me how it could work in C# ?
Thanks in advance.